# wp_clear_object_cache() is deprecated. What should I use instead?

Tags: wp-cli

Today I noticed that `\WP_CLI\Utils\wp_clear_object_cache()` has been marked as `deprecated` in WP-CLI `1.5.0`. The [release notes](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/releases/tag/v2.5.0) don't mention anything about it. What should be used, instead? Do I still need to take care of flushing the cache myself or is it handled automatically now, like [mentioned here](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/4617)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`wp_cache_flush()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_cache_flush/) should help you but is not the same one.

The function runs on the global `$wp_object_cache` and set a new empty array, different to the WP CLI deprecated function `wp_clear_object_cache` for different keys of the global var.

```php
function wp_clear_object_cache() {
    global $wpdb, $wp_object_cache;

    $wpdb->queries = [];

    if ( ! is_object( $wp_object_cache ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // The following are Memcached (Redux) plugin specific (see https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31463).
    if ( isset( $wp_object_cache->group_ops ) ) {
        $wp_object_cache->group_ops = [];
    }
    if ( isset( $wp_object_cache->stats ) ) {
        $wp_object_cache->stats = [];
    }
    if ( isset( $wp_object_cache->memcache_debug ) ) {
        $wp_object_cache->memcache_debug = [];
    }
    // Used by `WP_Object_Cache` also.
    if ( isset( $wp_object_cache->cache ) ) {
        $wp_object_cache->cache = [];
    }
}
```

**Note:** The deprecated flag should be wrong, and the maintenance team will change them in a future version. That is information after a small talk with the team.

Comment: Thank you! the `WP_CLI\Utils\ wp_clear_object_cache` doesn't just clear the full cache, it instead only deletes certain properties. Did they decide it's not necessary? I can't find an official opinion on this anywhere...

Comment: I ask Alain (WP CLI Dev Lead) and he means, the method is okay. Maybe the deprecated flag is wrong. He will check them. The difference between these two functions is clear. see https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/pull/4615/files

Comment: Thank you! Any news on this from Alain?

Comment: Not necessary, because he will leave this function and remove the flag deprecated  in one of the next releases.